# Error message using dissolve

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.5, dissolve

I'm trying to dissolve an hydrologic system because I have to many small portions for what I want to do but I can't figure how to make dissolve work ... the shapefile I'm using is a merge of different shapefiles (some I edited manually)

Here is how I set it up :

[image]

but when I execute it I get this message :

[image]

Do you know how I can fix this or if there is another way to reduce the number of entities in my attribute table? I have tried multipart to single part but it didn't reduce the number of items in my attribute table. 
Even having just one big entity could work ...

Comment: Your usage and goal don't seem compatible. If you check the "Make multipart features" it will actually dissolve all features into one (which is of course far too many parts for one feature). Please remember to always place the error message in the body of the question as ASCII text, so it is legible and searchable.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
the error message says that the geometry has no Z value, do you kowe what that means and if there is a solution ? 
the rivers are not all connected to each other but they're made of smaller portions so I was hoping to find a way to join each of the smaller portions into bigger parts. You don't think it's something possible ?

Comment: Very wrong long name for output. Anyway check environment setting regarding Z and see if your input is polylines Z.

Comment: Please always provide any error messages as text rather than pictures.